# Creating a professional notifications system

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a question reagrding AWS and Lambda functions, as I plan to design a notifications system for my app.

I have events and I want to send a reminder an hour before every event to every user attending. The dates are stored in the data base, as well as are the attending users. So I thought about the Lambda function which would send the notification to the user's device when it reached the right time.

However, is that possible with LAMBDA AWS to write such a function which would periodically look for this? I also wouldn't like to check it every-minute as it is quite costly then (I assume). How else I could design it?

Thank you in advance,
Grzegorz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, is that possible with LAMBDA AWS to write such a function
>   which would periodically look for this?

Yes, just write a function that queries the database to check for notifications that need to be sent, and schedule it to run periodically.

> I also wouldn't like to check it every-minute as it is quite costly
>   then (I assume). How else I could design it?

It probably wouldn't cost much at all, if it only runs for a few seconds each time it is invoked. However if this is an issue for you, then just schedule it to run less often. Every 15 minutes or something like that.

Comment: where is it in documentation? Can't find it

Comment: Where is what exactly? The documentation for scheduling recurring Lambda invocations? That is documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html